Python provider healthcheck doesn't detect virtualenv on MacOs
Switching from vim to neovim. I'm running:
MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1
brew installed pyenv and neovim
created a py3nvim virtualenv for neovim, as per the :help provider-python documentation
But I still get this error when I run :checkhealth
provider.python: require("provider.python.health").check()

Python 3 provider (optional)
- pyenv: Path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyenv/2.4.3/libexec/pyenv
- pyenv: Root: /Users/stan/.pyenv
- Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/Users/XXX/.pyenv/versions/py3nvim/bin/python"
- Executable: /Users/XXX/.pyenv/versions/py3nvim/bin/python
- Python version: 3.11.9
- pynvim version: 0.5.0
- OK Latest pynvim is installed.

Python virtualenv ~
- ERROR Failed to run healthcheck for "provider.python" plugin. Exception:
  ...0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/lua/provider/python/health.lua:20: Usage: /Users/XXX/.pyenv/versions/py3nvim/bin/python3-config [--prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--extension-suffix|--    help|--abiflags|--configdir|--embed]

When I run /Users/XXX/.pyenv/versions/py3nvim/bin/python3-config I get the following output:
Usage: /Users/XXX/.pyenv/versions/py3nvim/bin/python3-config [--prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--extension-suffix|--help|--abiflags|--configdir|--embed]

My init.vim file contains:
let g:python3_host_prog ='/Users/XXX/.pyenv/versions/py3nvim/bin/python'
let g:loaded_perl_provider = 0
let g:loaded_ruby_provider = 0

Help is welcome, I have tried everything, including modifing the health.lua file according to gpt-4o answers but it's making me run in circles.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've now spent many hours on this issue to no avail

I am also using neovim with pyenv on MacOS and the following lines are working for me:
-- init.lua
local home = os.getenv('HOME')
vim.env.PYENV_VERSION = vim.fn.system('pyenv version'):match('(%S+)%s+%(.-%)')
vim.g.python3_host_prog = home .. "/.pyenv/shims/python3"

